# make statements in postgres function behave atomically

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I have the following postgres function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_materialized_view(name)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  _table_name ALIAS FOR $1;
  _entry materialized_views%ROWTYPE;
  _result INT;
BEGIN

  SELECT * INTO _entry FROM materialized_views WHERE table_name = _table_name;

  BEGIN;
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE new_materialized_view_rows ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT * FROM ' || _entry.view_name;
    EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || _table_name;
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || _table_name || ' SELECT * FROM new_materialized_view_rows';

    UPDATE materialized_views
    SET    last_refresh = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE  table_name = _table_name;
  COMMIT;

  EXECUTE 'ANALYZE ' || table_name; 
  RETURN 1;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;

ALTER FUNCTION refresh_materialized_view(name) OWNER TO portal;
```

The function is called from a non-transactional context, so I've enclosed the statements that update data with

```
BEGIN; 

COMMIT;
```

so that these statements execute atomically. However, when I execute the script above I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 16:   BEGIN;
```

Answer (score 1):

A function is always part of the *calling* transaction. You cannot commit the transaction in a function. So you will need to do the following in the calling code:

```
begin;
select efresh_materialized_view('foobar');
commit;
```

"*The function is called from a non-transactional context*"
That is not possible. You cannot work without a transaction in PostgreSQL. You are probably referring to the "autocommit" mode which implicitely commits every *statement* - but that is still transactional.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use COMMIT within a function. The function is transactional anyway, that's why you don't need the second BEGIN; as well. This is your bug as well, this is where it fails.